# Cambio de formato de fecha en español en php de texto a dd/mm/aaa

Tags: php, date

Hay alguna manera rápida de cambiar de fecha en modo texto a a fecha en formato dd/mm/aaaa en lenguaje PHP
ejemplo:
VEINTICINCO DÍAS DEL MES DE MAYO DEL AÑO DOS MIL DIECISIETE ---> 25/05/2017
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo.Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con **NumberFormatter**

```
$fecha = explode('/','25/05/2017');
$nf = new NumberFormatter("sp", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$d = $nf->format($fecha[0]);
$m = $nf->format($fecha[1]);
$a = $nf->format($fecha[2]);
echo  $d . ' dias del mes ' . $m . ' del año ' . $a;
```

Comment: Espera, su pregunta es a la inversa; quiere convertir un texto en fecha.

Comment: Exacto es justo al reves, de VEINTICINCO DÍAS DEL MES DE MAYO DEL AÑO DOS MIL DIECISIETE a 25/05/2017